# Python Server Reply

Tags: python, server, tcp, debian

I want to get a response from Python server depending on the entered data.
If i enter UPPER I'd like to receive "Upper Case", LOWER - "Lower Case".
In my opinion I did everything good but it still doesn't work it looks like:

```
~#: telnet localhost 5005
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Available commands: UPPER, LOWER
UPPER
```

and nothing happen next.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
conn.sendall('Available commands: UPPER, LOWER\n')
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data == 'UPPER':
        conn.send('Upper case')
    elif data == 'LOWER':
        conn.send('Lower case')
    elif data == 'QUIT':
        break
    print "received data:", data
conn.close()
```

My version of python is 2.7.13  and i'm trying to do it on Debian.

Comment: What das "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message? Do you get an unexpected response? No response at all?

Comment: After entering the data for example UPPER nothing happens - it just moves to a new empty line in command line.

Comment: a bit off-topic, but: Python2.7? are you aware that Python2 has seen EOL at the beginning of 2020 - more than a year ago (it's dead. the EOL has been announced for years, but in 2020 they finally pulled it throuhg). if you are new to Python, don't touch Python2. Use the shiny Python3 instead!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the line:  data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
to:  data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('UTF-8')

It it doesn't help, you should put your client code here as well. It will make it easier to help you with your problem.